# menu() in R takes subsequent code as input

Tags: r

I am trying to include a prompt in a function inside an r script. The main aim is that a user can select, which data should be chosen. Then the processing continues.
I tried to achieve that by using `menu()` from `utils`. However, the execution of the code does not stop. It displays the promt in the console, but the code execution goes on, which results in the next code line becoming the user response for the `menu()` call.

Here a minimal example:

```
select_data <- function(dat) {
  
  resp <- menu(c("1", "2", "3"), title = "Choose number of carburetors")
  
  sel_dat <- dat %>%
    filter(carb == resp)
  
  return(sel_dat)
}

calc_mean_hp <- function(dat) {
  
  mean_hp <- mean(dat$hp)
  
  return(mean_hp)
}

selected <- select_data(mtcars)

hp <- calc_mean_hp(selected)
```

Running the whole code results in `hp <- calc_mean_hp(selected)` being taken as the user input for the `menu()` call. I get that `menu()` just takes as an input whatever comes next, but can I somehow halt the code execution at the `menu()` call or do I need find another solution?

Cheers.

Comment: I cannot reproduce any error, after the menu selection the function returns a subset of the data and the mean value is the same as if I had grouped by `carb` and computed the mean value of `hp`.

Comment: *How* are you “running the whole code”? If you source the file, this will work. If you copy & paste it into the terminal, it (of course) won’t.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: I highlight the whole code and run everything (in RStudio). I know that it would work by running the two functions seperately, but I want to provide users (with little R knowledge) with a script that they can just run from top to bottom.

Comment: @MichaelF Yes, that probably has the same effect as copying and pasting the lines into the terminal. To provide users with a script I would recommend you either package the script so that it can be run *outside RStudio* (trivial on macOS and Linux — just add a shebang line —, harder on Windows), or instruct users to run the script inside RStudio by using the “Source” button (better yet, “Source as Local Job …”, but that might be too complicated for them).

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Thanks for the suggestions, I will look into the sourcing options. This soounds promising. In the worst case I might instruct the users to run the code in two batches (one until after the function including the `menu()` and then the rest.

Answer (score 0):

An option would be to include the `mean` calculation in the same function as `menu`.

```
select_data_and_return_mean <- function(dat) {
  
  resp <- menu(c("1", "2", "3"), title = "Choose number of carburetors")
  sel_dat <- dat %>%  filter(carb == resp)
  mean_hp <- mean(sel_dat$hp)
  return(mean_hp)
}

selected <- select_data_and_return_mean(mtcars)

Choose number of carburetors 

1: 1
2: 2
3: 3

Selection: 2

selected
#[1] 117.2
```

Comment: Thanks, the issue is that there is more code that (im my code) follows after the mean (sorry, I did not mention this before). So ideally the code execution should stop and wait until the input is given and then resume execution.